# slow hardware inspiron i7 with ssd

Tags: performance, ssd

I got notebook dell inspiron i7 8gb ram and ssd 480gb. but its slow as hell. I do not know if the ssd is almost dead or something else. I installed ubuntu 20 and ran some software to check the hardware, but no negative response. Can some1 help me?

I already change the bios config to factory settings.

TY vm

Comment: 1. This is of topic on Stack-Overflow but Ok on Super-User. 2. Consider providing more informations starting from profiling ones (eg. average disk bandwidth, length of the disk queue, RAM infos and CPU usage) and hardware infos

Comment: 1. Which i7? There are 12 generations of i7 and some of them are significantly slower than modern i3. 2. What exactly is slow and how slow?